# c++ SDL rectangle app stops working

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to get a rectangle on the screen using sdl with c++. The file compiles but it stops working and returns 255. Can you recommend me something better please?

here is the code:

```
  SDL_Window* window;

  SDL_Rect* SrcR; //rectangle
  SDL_Rect* DestR; //dist rectangle

  SrcR->x = 0;
  SrcR->y = 0;
  SrcR->w = SHAPE_SIZE;
  SrcR->h = SHAPE_SIZE;

  DestR->x = 100 / 2 - SHAPE_SIZE / 2;
  DestR->y = 50 / 2 - SHAPE_SIZE / 2;
  DestR->w = SHAPE_SIZE;
  DestR->h = SHAPE_SIZE;

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  window = SDL_CreateWindow("title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 200, 250, NULL);

  SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
  renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
  SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;

  SDL_Surface* surface;
  surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
  SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 255, 0, 0));
  texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

  SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

  SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, SrcR, DestR); //here i got error before

  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Comment: Check what the SDL_* functions return - one of them probably failed for some reason. Checking if function calls succeed is a good idea in general...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `SDL_Rect` incorrectly. You have defined it a pointer (see below) but you never allocate memory for it. You then try to allocate values to the rects which you have also failed to initialize so could have any old garbage address in.

```
SDL_Rect* SrcR; //rectangle
SDL_Rect* DestR; //dist rectangle

SrcR->x = 0;
SrcR->y = 0;
SrcR->w = SHAPE_SIZE;
SrcR->h = SHAPE_SIZE;

DestR->x = 100 / 2 - SHAPE_SIZE / 2;
DestR->y = 50 / 2 - SHAPE_SIZE / 2;
DestR->w = SHAPE_SIZE;
DestR->h = SHAPE_SIZE;
```

Should be as follows:

```
SDL_Rect SrcR; //rectangle
SDL_Rect DestR; //dist rectangle

SrcR.x = 0;
SrcR.y = 0;
SrcR.w = SHAPE_SIZE;
SrcR.h = SHAPE_SIZE;

DestR.x = 100 / 2 - SHAPE_SIZE / 2;
DestR.y = 50 / 2 - SHAPE_SIZE / 2;
DestR.w = SHAPE_SIZE;
DestR.h = SHAPE_SIZE;
```

or you can directly initialize them as follows:

```
SDL_Rect SrcR = {0, 0, SHAPE_SIZE, SHAPE_SIZE};
SDL_Rect DestR = {(50 - SHAPE_SIZE/2), (25 - SHAPE_SIZE/2), SHAPE_SIZE, SHAPE_SIZE};
```

Finally when making a call to `SDL_RenderCopy` remember that you are now using an instance rather than a pointer so you will need to pass the address of the rects:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, &SrcR, &DestR);
```

You should definitely get some error checking on the SDL_* functions as mentioned in a comment especially where you are obtaining pointers from funtions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked and I finished the project xD